# How to replace rows with columns in QSqlTableModel?

Tags: replace, transform, rows, qsqltablemodel

I found a lot of answers how to transform rows into columns in SQL. But I need to transforms rows into columns in QSqlTableModel.
As I understand it should not be a very difficult task but I can't find any idea of how to realize it.
Perhaps data(), setData() and some other methods could be reimplemented, but I am afraid to miss something...

Or, maybe, some methods of QTableView should be reimplemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand QIdentityProxyModel could be used to solve this problem.
Unfortunately, QIdentityProxyModel is available since version 4.8.

So I inherited QAbstractProxyModel and implemented mapToSource() and mapFromSource(), rowCount(), columnCount() and few more methods to switch rows with columns.

Comment: Showing the code of your subclass(es) here would have been really helpful to the next person coming along with the same question. ;-)